# What is the meaning of this number displayed in my R environment?

Tags: soft-question

My question is really silly, I want to know what the meaning of this number displayed in my R environment, is it $2.2\times e^{-16}$?

[image]

Comment: That should be $\cdots \times 10^{-16}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.2e-16 means $ 2.2 \times 10^{-16}$.  It is a shorthand convention for scientific notation hanging over, I think, originally from Fortran programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's weird, so the $e=10$ and the $-$ symbol doesn't mean the negative sign.

Comment: Oh, the minus sign absolutely should have relevance here.  @WADon probably just made a typo.  `2.2e16` (*also sometimes `2.2e+16`*) should be in reference to $2.2\times 10^{16}$ but `2.2e-16` would instead be $2.2\times 10^{-16}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited myself

Comment: As for $e$ "*equaling $10$*", that is not quite accurate.  It is more that it is being used as an operator, one which takes the number on the left and multiplies that by $10$ to the power of the number on the right... often for stylistic reasons and display limitations.

Comment: Yes - a typo, for which apologies, and thanks for correcting.  The 'e' just stands for exponent.  The convention is also used by many calculators, being convenient when the space on the display is limited.